# Why some of these kotlin coroutines are never launched?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Basically I'm having a weird behavior and I couldn't find still the solution. Basically I have a few instances of this Myclass. After calling start() they are supposed to enter in an infinite loop. They are polling some data with kafka in these loops and then using an actor they are caching some data or incrementing a counter (let's keep it simple).

However, I'm observing that only 2 of these coroutines with the infinite loop are launched while the others are not. How is it possible?

```
class Myclass{
    private val job = Job()
    private val jobScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + job)
    private val myclassWithAnActor = MyClassWithAnActor()

    fun start() {
        jobScope.launch {    
             while (jobScope.isActive) {                
                ......
                myclassWithAnActor.cachedata(data)
             }
        }
}
```

Where my class with an actor is defined like this:

```
class MyClassWithAnActor(): CoroutineScope {
    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Default + job

    private val actor = actor<IntentionMsg> {
        for (message in channel) {                  
              ....
        }
    }

    suspend fun cacheData(data: ...){
       actor.send(.....)
    }
}
```

Then I have this:

```
val myclass1 = MyClass()
val myclass2 = MyClass()
val myclass3 = MyClass()
val myclass4 = MyClass()

myclass1.start()
myclass2.start()
myclass3.start()
myclass4.start()
```

And for my surprise, only 2 of them are launched

Comment: might be a stupid comment to leave, but I guess that you have checked that your machine has more than 2 CPU cores? `Dispatchers.Default` by default has the maximum number of threads equal to the number of CPU cores, with a min of 2.

Comment: I will check tomorrow at the job, might be not stupid because it happens that when I deploy this, it behaves as I described, but in my laptop it works perfectly fine. So there might be a difference in the amount of CPUs, I will try to confirm as soon as I can. Thanks for the idea, maybe is that

Comment: I confirm I have only two CPU cores. Seems that I need at least one more. Thanks a lot for the info

Comment: You can use another dispatcher, or create your own, that would use more than that. For example Dispatches.IO will use the max allowed (it should only be used for IO, but just an example)

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem I got because of the amount of CPUs I was using. 2 CPUs in this case, not enough